# how to get user profile with azure ad in flutter

Tags: azure, flutter, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

how can I retrieve current user profile from an azure ad in flutter mobile app
I have used [this flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth/example) and followed the example(not b2c). I can only retrieve the Access Token but not the user data like email and user names.

Is there anyone who got this?

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with Flutter but to get the information about a user, you will need to use [`Microsoft Graph API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).

I searched for `Microsoft Graph` using this link: https://pub.dev/packages?q=microsoft+graph and it showed me some packages. Hopefully you should be able to pick the right package.

Comment: I have used one [msgraph](https://pub.dev/packages?q=microsoft+graph) and passed access token in it. It returns cordinated values

Comment: What do you mean by coordinated values? Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: I got it, I used graph api not any flutter packages thanks for the help though